# iPhone can't seem to keep connection to server using socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm creating a browser-based app using node.js and socket.io. It allows users to create a game, and join a room using a room code (sort of like Jackbox Games, if you've seen that). Here's the problem I'm having. On my laptop, the connection stays open, but if I connect with my phone, the connection randomly closes. I've confirmed this as follows:

On the client side, I have this code:

```
const socket = io();

socket.on('ping', (data) => {
  showMessage('info', 'ping', 500);
  socket.emit('pong', data);
});

socket.on('error', (data) => {
  showMessage('error', data.message, 2000);
});
```

We initialize the socket, and then just immediately emit a 'pong' whenever the server sends us a 'ping'. ShowMessage is a function that flashes a message on screen - here's it's merely diagnostic.

On the server side, I have:

```
const socket = (http, server) => {
  const io = require('socket.io')(http, {
    pingInterval: 1000,
    pingTimeout: 1000,
  });
  io.listen(server);

  setInterval(() => {
    pingTime = Date.now();
    io.emit('ping', null);
  }, pingInterval);

  io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log(`A user has connected from ${socket.handshake.address}`);
    console.log(`\tID: ${socket.id}`);
  }
}
```

Here's the problem. On my computer, I can go to localhost:3000 and see the "ping" message blinking on the screen. It keeps going until I kill the server. When I do it on my iPhone 11 (using Chrome), the "ping" message blinks for a bit, and then stops, presumably as the socket is closed. The pingInterval and pingTimeout settings on the server side mean that the socket will reconnect pretty quickly. Unfortunately, as the app I'm trying to build is a buzzer for a speed-based game (think Jeopardy - first person to hit the button gets to answer the question), just reconnecting alone isn't good enough - I would really prefer it if the socket would stay open. Is there a way to force it to stay open?

Comment: socket.io already has automatic reconnection logic.  It's unclear why you're trying to implement your own.

Comment: We would need to see more of your overall socket.io code to have any idea whether you are doing something wrong.  Socket.io is not known to be unstable on iPhone.  All mobile browsers reserve the right to shut things down that aren't actively being used in the foreground (for power consumption reasons), but it's unclear if that applies here.

Comment: Is your server on the public internet or a local server on your private home or company network?  Have you added listeners for all the various socket.io error, disconnect and reconnect messages?  Have you turned on verbose logging for socket.io so you can track everything that's going on?

Comment: I read up on reconnection logic and amended my post - the problem remains.

Comment: To answer your questions - I took only the relevant code and ran it on my private home network - almost all of the code is now up there. It appears that the browser is shutting down the socket connection, but I'd like to force it to stay open. If that's not possible then I guess I'm hosed unless there's a workaround somehow - I really don't want to set the pingTimeout/pingInterval to something really small and force the browser to re-render the page so often (even if the page isn't huge or resource-intensive)